# Auto Suggest : Substring matching

Tags: java, c++, data-structures

I am trying to implement auto suggest using ternary search tree(TST),but TST is useful when we are looking for prefix searches, how can we implement Auto Suggest for sub string matches also?
Is there any other data structure which can be used?

Eg of substring matches :
When I am trying to search for UML using auto suggest , even the string "Beginners Guide for UML" should match.

Comment: I suggest you looking up on [Fusion-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_tree) or [Suffix Trees] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)

Answer (score 1):

This is from the top of my head, not any proper and proven data structure/algorithm:

1. Select a mapping of all legal characters to N symbols (for simplicity: 26 symbols for latin letters and similar non-latin letters ignoring case + 1 for non-letters = total 27 symbols).
2. From your dictionary, create a shallow tree with max branching factor of N (ie. quite high). Leaf nodes would contain references to all words which contain the symbol combo leading from root to that leaf, (intermediate nodes might contain references to words which are shorter than depth of a leaf node, or you could just ignore words which are that short).
3. Depth of tree would be variable, probably in range of 1..4, so that each leaf node would contain about same number of words (same word of course listed under many leaves, like MATCH under leaves MAT, ATC, TCH if tree depth happened to be 3).
4. When user is entering letters, follow the tree as far as it goes, until you're left with relatively small set of words. Then do linear filtering on remaining words after you're at leaf of the tree and user enters more text to match. Optionally filter out symbol matches which actually aren't character matches, though it might be nice to match also `äöO` when user enters `ao0`, etc.
5. Optimize number of symbols you map your chars to, to have good branching factor for the tree. Optimize words per leaf to have decent memory usage without having too many words to filter linearly after reaching leaf of the tree.

---

Of course there are actual researched algorithms for finding a string (what user entered) in a large piece of text (all the phrases/words you want to match), like [Aho–Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) and [Rabin–Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), which are probably worth investigating.